# Double free or corruption C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, queue, malloc, free

I'm getting an odd error which occurs even though I am calling free(), the use is in a method called dequeue which removes elements from a priority queue, the functionality works fine but when the queue is empty the error is thrown instead of the error message which is defined.

Code and Error below:

```
void enqueue(string item, long time)
    {
        cout<<"Please Enter Entry and Time of element you wish to enqueue.."<<endl;
        PRecord *tmp, *q;
        tmp = new PRecord;
        tmp->entry = item;
        tmp->time = time;
        if(front==NULL){ //if queue is empty
            tmp->link = front;
            front = tmp;    
        }
        if(time<=front->time){ //if newer priority item comes through put it at front of queue
            tmp->link = front;
            front = tmp;    
        }

        else {
            q = front;
            while (q->link != NULL && q->link->time <= time)
                q=q->link;
            tmp->link = q->link;
            q->link = tmp;


        }
                   }

int dequeue()
        {try{
            PRecord *tmp; //pointer to front of queue

            if(front!=NULL){
                tmp = front;
                cout<<"Deleted item is: "<<endl;
                displayRecord(tmp); //outputs record details
                front = front->link; //link to the front

                free(tmp); //dealloc memory no longer used


            }
            else{
            cerr<<"Queue is empty - No items to dequeue!"<<endl;    
                }
        } catch(...){
            return(0);
        }

            }





*** glibc detected *** ./3x: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000bb3040 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x35a8675dee]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x35a8678c3d]
./3x[0x401275]
./3x[0x400f69]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x35a861ed1d]
./3x[0x400d59]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2623369                            /home/std/rc14lw/lab5excercisefinal/3x
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:06 2623369                            /home/std/rc14lw/lab5excercisefinal/3x
00bb3000-00bd4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
35a8200000-35a8220000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1310722                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
```

Comment: Why the thumbs down? The question has all the requirements and is clear and concise.

Comment: how did you allocate and intitialize your PRecords ? Is there a valid reason why you go for malloc/free instead of new/delete ?

Comment: Added my enqueue method to show allocation of PRecords, the same behavior is there when I use delete

Comment: @rahulchawla _"The question has all the requirements..."_ - no, it does not. Namely, it does not provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Anyway, you create an object with `new` and then deallocate with `free`. This is **undefined behavior** (and it does not invoke destructor `~PRecord()`). Do `delete tmp;` instead.

Comment: as you can see @DanielLangr I tried delete aswell, thanks for the help I rafix got the solution

Comment: @rahulchawla there are some interesting answers now. But in any case, c++ is not c. So new/delete or new[]/delete[] and forget malloc()/free().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When queue is empty, after adding first item you should return from `enqueue` function, without it you make that `front` **points to itself**.

Solution:

```
       if(front==NULL)
       {   //if queue is empty
            tmp->link = front;
            front = tmp;    
            return; // <-- added
        }
```

Without return you have an issue because `front` points to itself:

By these lines you create first item:

```
tmp = new PRecord;
tmp->entry = item;
tmp->time = time;
if(front==NULL){ //if queue is empty
    tmp->link = front;
    front = tmp;    
}
```

then you check the following condition `if(time<=front->time){` which returns true, it is obvious, `time` are equal, then this line

```
tmp->link = front;
```

makes that `front` points to itself, because `tmp == front` and `front` is not NULL. That is why your `dequeue` function doesn't work.

Comment: Thank-you for the clear and concise answer - makes complete sense and I actually learned something! Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you insert your first entry twice into the list, and subsequently delete it two times, that's when the error is printed.

You first check if the list is empty, if so add the new entry as first entry.
Then you compare the time of the new entry with the time of the first entry, which is the same entry if it is the first, then you insert the entry again.

In other words: You need an "else if" there:

```
    if(front==NULL){ //if queue is empty
        tmp->link = front;
        front = tmp;    
    } else if (time<=front->time){ //  <-- there is the else you need to add
        tmp->link = front;
        front = tmp;    
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the input this may work aswell, but I saw rafix's answer first. Thank you once again!

Comment: @rahulchawla Sure. Just, in terms of coding style, I would then always use `return`, i.e. not use `return` in the first `if` and the have `if .. else` afterwards.